# How to sum up products like this?

Tags: spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

I am creating a spreadsheet to keep track of large expenses. The idea is that I virtually finance things rather than actually do it that way when budgeting.

The idea is that if I make a large purchase I can spread out its cost over a certain amount of months, mentally.

The first part of this is the following table and I cant quite figure out how to do it.

[image]

So just to walk you through the math a bit I bought a headlamp on 12/12/18 and wish to “finance” it over 4 months. This means that 4*30 days after 12/12/18 I will have paid it off. In the meantime I will be spending 0.42$ every day to meet this goal.

I also have a stitch fix order that I wish to “finance” over 6 months meaning that after 12/11/18 I will need to be spending 0.43$ towards its cost.

So this then brings me to the chart data table. The goal of this table is to help me visualize things over time. The debt table should allow me to create a graph where new purchases cause spikes that overall go down over time.

The weekly costs table would keep track of the accumulated “price per day” costs for the week in question. You can imagine when a new thing is purchased it creates a small spike that moves out over multiple months.

So onto the formulas. The debt one is fairly simple. Given a date `d` for each expense on date`e` with `c` daily cost and `m` total cost sum up the following formula `m-clamp((e-d),0,inf)*c` to get your value. The problem is that as you can see from the screenshot I have no idea how to do this form of formula in Numbers.

The weekly cost is a bit trickier. Given a start date`d1` and an end date `d2` and an expense on date `e` of daily cost `c` and `m` total cost financing over period `p` first calculate the number of days you are paying expenses for using the following variables

```
Start = clamp(e-d1,0,inf)
End = clamp(d2-(e+p*30),0,inf)
Days = (d2-d1)-Start-End
```

Then your amount for that period of time is simply `Days*c` however again this is not a formula I know how to express in Numbers.

Can anyone help me out here?